# Select where all columns in list item

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I do the equivalent of the following in SQL Server?

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.TableA 
WHERE (ColA, ColB, ColC) IN ((1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1));
```

I only want to match rows where

```
(ColA = 1 AND Col2 = 2 AND Col3 = 3) OR 
(ColA = 1 AND Col2 = 1 AND Col3 = 1)
```

There can be an arbitrary number of match conditions.

The only solution I have been able to find is the above, but doubt it would scale to 1000s of dynamic values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put those value in temp table or use [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Use [INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Set Operator

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dbo.TableA 
WHERE  EXISTS
       (
           SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
           INTERSECT
           SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
           FROM
           (
               VALUES
               (1, 2, 3),
               (1, 1, 1)
           ) v (ColA, ColB, ColC)
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support this tuple syntax, so you'll have to use the more verbose version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TableA
WHERE (ColA = 1 AND ColB = 2 AND ColC = 3) OR
      (ColA = 1 AND ColB = 1 AND ColC = 1);
```

For many tuples, you really should have the values in some other table.  Then, you could simply join to that table to get the filtering effect you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TableA a
INNER JOIN FilterTable b
    ON b.ColA = a.ColA AND
       b.ColB = a.ColB AND
       b.ColC = a.ColC;
```

Comment: Is there any way to scale this to 1000 conditions without simple string interpolation?